# Simple question on the antiderivative of a two variable function (or distribution)?

Tags: integration, terminology, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, step-function

I am confused about antiderivatives of multivariable functions, specifically $\delta(ct-|x|)$ and $\delta(t-|x/c|)$.

Here $\delta(.)$ is the Dirac delta function (distribution)and $x$ and $t$ are variables and $c$ is a constant $>0$.

MY QUESTION IS: *What variable(s) are the antiderivative integrals of $\delta(ct-|x|)$ or $\delta(t-|x/c|)$ with respect to, are there separate antiderivatives for each variable (what do they look like), is there such a thing as a 'total antiderivative'?*

I know these antiderivatives lead to Heaviside step functions.

Comment: Usually the antiderivative is taken of $\delta(\cdot)$, but it's generally impossible to say without a context.

Comment: I edited my question. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Still: Your question can not be answered without context. One can take the antiderivative w.r.t. all of $ct-|x|$ (or $t-|x/c|$), w.r.t. $t$, or try to find some w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: So I think you answered most of my question--it was about those alternatives. Can you write that up with the integrals as an answer?

Comment: Are you familiar with the "jump formula" for the derivative of a piece-wise $C^1$ function? Consider the indicator function defined as $f(x,t) = 1$ for $t\ge |x|$ and $f(x,t)=0$ for $t < |x|$. Can you find its derivative w.r.t. $x$ for a given $t\ne0$?

Comment: I assume you mean the Heaviside distribution $f(x,t)=\theta(t-|x|)$?